# wrote a React code snippet to implement conditional rendering and am not able to update the state of {Left} and {Right}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The terminal/console returns no error. I am confused as to where I am going wrong.
The handleLeftClicks() is used to render the # of times the left button is clicked and respectively for right.
The allClicks within History component is meant to render total # of clicks.
I am unable to update both {left} and {right}.
I tried console logging both the functions but couldn't get an output in the console.

I really apologise if this newbie question wasted your time.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const History = (props) => {
  if (props.allClicks.length === 0) {
    return <div>The app is used by pressing the buttons</div>;
  }

  return <div>button press history: {props.allClicks.join(" ")}</div>;
};

const Button = ({ handleClick, text }) => (
  <button onClick={handleClick}>{text}</button>
);

const App = () => {
  const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
  const [right, setRight] = useState(0);

  const [allClicks, setAll] = useState([]);

  const handleLeftClicks = () => {
    console.log("left click");

    setAll(allClicks.concat("L"));
    setLeft(left + 1);
  };

  const handleRightClicks = () => {
    console.log("right click");

    setAll(allClicks.concat("R"));
    setRight(right + 1);
  };
  console.log(left);
  console.log(right);
  console.log(allClicks);

  return (
    <div>
      {left}
      <Button handleClick={handleLeftClicks} text="left" />

      <Button handleClick={handleRightClicks} text="right" />

      {right}

      <History allClicks={allClicks} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a wrong prop to `Button` component.
It should be `handleClick` instead of `onClick`.

```
<Button handleClick={handleLeftClicks} text="left" />
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-euler-sri3o?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Antariksh, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused, Now I have realised that its not  a user defined variable I guess. thank you for answering!